# MariaDB 10.2 json insert not valid with PHP

Tags: php, sql, json, serialization, mariadb

I'm trying to save a lot of data inside my MariaDB 10.2 database with JSON. The data contain's `' " / \ |` and a lot more special characters.

When I do `json_encode` and after that directly `json_decode` I got a nice working array, however, when I use `json_encode` and saves it to the database and after I select the column and do `json_decode` it will return NULL in PHP. Also `JSON_VALID('ms_routing_data')` in SQL returns mostly 0.

Before this, all my data was stored serialized in the database without having problems with special characters.

Here I have an example of my script and data from my database.
https://pastebin.com/EWvFr10p

Comment: Can you show us your data?

Comment: @Script47 It's a lot of data, and in some way sensitive. I will try to replace all the data with shorter and 'public-data' it will only take some time, or is there an option for showing it privately?

Comment: Questions are public and any code / examples should remain that way too, we can't exclude people from seeing it as a result, try and replicate it with dummy data.

Comment: I am currently working on replicate of the problem with dummy data

Comment: I created this Pastebin with dummy data and part of my script. https://pastebin.com/EWvFr10p

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me with this?

Comment: If you will be using UTF-8, use `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` on `json_encode()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my problem solved. It was easier than I thought it would be.

I can just use the most basic variant of `json_encode()` without flags. All I needed to is adding `mysqli_real_escape_string()` on my insert. Now all my data returns valid JSON.